# Change text view

Tags: java, android-studio, parse-platform

I already have a login activity and now I want the name to change according to the name registered in a profile activity.

```
 nameTextView.setText(usernameEditText.getText().toString());
```

I already tried to use this code but the app crash.
Im using parse.
Anyone can help me?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

better to send the user name via bandle than use the name in edit text directly

more info here https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html